# Select/query months from time DataArray in 3D Dataset

Tags: python, time, dataset, python-xarray

I have a problem concerning the selection of different months in my data. The data is stored in a dataset of three dimensions (lat, lon, time) and as I want to apply different corrections dependent on the season, I need to select the data correspondingly. Actually I would just need to query somehow to prove this data format regarding the 6th and 7th character and then apply an if condition.
1990-01-01T01:00:00.000000000

But I can not manage to adress the month.

Can anybody help me with that?

[I provided an image of the structure of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAIEA.png)